# Is it possible to make a template with no ContentType to fetch arbitrary data in Bolt CMS?

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm in the process of building an education site, with Departments, Courses, and Modules (all working out fine so far).

I need to make a custom Timetable page that will fetch all Modules of all Courses and plot them into a weekly calendar.

I've setup a menu entry for /calendar and made a calendar.twig template, but since there is no ContentType called Calendar the template cannot be found.

Making a ContentType for Calendar doesn't really make sense since the Calendar will be fetching and displaying Modules and Courses, for which there are already working templates.

Is there a way to setup a menu option / route to a template with no specific pre-fetched content, allowing me to just pull in everything I need via twig 'setcontent' to build my calendar? Or does this go against the grain of Bolt?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there is support for exactly this (in Bolt 3.0) just putting the answer here in case it helps anyone else.

I added this to my routing.yml and it now works as expected, allowing me to fetch any content via twig:

```
templatebinding:
    path: /calendar
    defaults:
        _controller: controller.frontend:template
        template: calendar
```